# ejabberd register user for only one domain

Tags: ejabberd

With ejabberd 18.12
I have two virtual hosts:

- domain1.tld
- domain2.tld

When I do the command

```
ejabberdctl register foo domain1.tld password
```

The user is also registered for domain2.tld.

Is there anyway to register a user for just one domain?

For example, foo@domain1.tld and foo@domain2.tld should not be the same account

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Important note about virtual hosting: if you define several domains in
>   ejabberd.yml (see section Host Names), you probably want that each
>   virtual host uses a different configuration of database

and also read https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/#relational-databases

You are using the same database for different vhosts.

Comment: That was it. Ejabberd now has a new mysql schema allowing for a single database to provide for multiple virtual hosts independently with the new schema. This is what I ended up doing and it is working.  `The 'new' schema allows to handle several XMPP domains in a single ejabberd database`